# Execute Run Command In Android Programmatically

Tags: android, ffmpeg, command-prompt, runcommand

The way when i execute command in run window in window 7 like:-
C:\Users\Nitin\Desktop\pradeet t\bin> ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -i input_file -map 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy D:\ad.mp4

Now i want to execute this in Android Programmatically. but i am unable to execute this command.

Please give my any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an executable like that on Android. What you should be doing is using an Android library for ffmpeg, there are a few around. [Try this tutorial](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial) on how to get started, it comes with source code and documentation.